# Strange behaviour with longtable

Tags: longtable

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{longtable}{p{8cm}}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

OK, no problem since the contents of the table is not enough to make the table pass to the next page.

So, inserting more dummy text inside the table (`\lipsum[3-8]` for example), we obtain

[image]

Why the result is not the derided one? Also, how to no indent the `longtable`, that is, how to flush it left?

Comment: The second question: use the optional argument: `\begin{longtable}[l]{p{8cm}}` or `\begin{longtable}[r]{p{8cm}}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thanks. So easy. How couldn't imagined it?

Comment: It's longtable users, not longtable, that have strange behaviour.

Comment: Well, after the explanation and the solution I have to agree with you, @DavidCarlisle. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. LaTeX will never break a page within a `p{<length>}` row. Page breaks only occur between rows of the table or at `\hline` commands. In the seemingly odd case you mention with `\lipsum[3-8]`, what happens is that all your six paragraphs are in the same row of the `p{8cm}` column, so no page break will be produced; the whole table gets pushed to the second page and typeset there, protruding to the bottom.
2. Use the optional argument: `\begin{longtable}[l]{p{8cm}}` or `\begin{longtable}[r]{p{8cm}}`.

An example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{8cm}}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, the problem is that each paragraph coming from `lipsum` is `p{}` and then will not be broken?

Comment: The problem is that all your paragraphs are inside one same `p{...}` row.

Comment: Ow, I see. I'm not using `\\` to change line. So, the ideal in this case would be to use another kind of box, not long table.

Comment: @Sigur A list or a `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, perhaps? It depends on what you are trying to achieve.